# Работа с процессами на C#

Tags: c#, .net, процесс

Как получить объём используемой оперативной памяти текущих процессов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно узнать количество физической памяти, то необходимо использовать [WorkingSet64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_WorkingSet64), что дает «объем физической памяти, выделенной для соответствующего процесса.» Также можно использовать [PeakWorkingSet64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_PeakWorkingSet64), что дает «максимальное количество физической памяти, используемой для соответствующего процесса»

Все процессы:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    string memoryUse = (p.WorkingSet64 / 1024).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"Process ID: {p.Id}, Process Name: {p.ProcessName}, Memory usage: {memoryUse}");
}
```

Определенный процесс:

```
Process[] name = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcessName");
foreach (Process p in name)
{
    string memoryUse = (p.PagedMemorySize64 / 1024).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"Memory usage: {memoryUse}");
}
```

Comment: Исходя из темы вопроса, я так понимаю, что нужны все текущие процессы. В таком случае нужно использовать Process.GetProcesses()

Comment: @МаксЖуков да возможно и так.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно узнать общее использование памяти:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
int memoryUse = 0;

foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    memoryUse += p.PagedMemorySize64 / 1024;
}

Console.WriteLine($"PC Memory usage: {memoryUse}");
```

Если нужны юзеджи каждого отдельного процесса то использовать ответ MiT